# "sku" in checkout config provider. magento 2

Tags: magento2, sku

I have something like this in my custom js file to fill an array of items with checkout config provider.

```
window.checkoutConfig.totalsData.items.forEach(function(item,index,array){
                products[index] = item;
                console.log(index);
                });
```

but apparently this does not contain the "sku" in the product details. How could I get this value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is `window.checkoutConfig.quoteItemData`. This is an array of objects with the complete set of data for each product. for example:

```
var firstProductSku = window.checkoutConfig.quoteItemData[0].sku
```